# Is there anyway to test Postgres with WPF by using Moq?

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, moq

I have try to take a look from https://developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/ as an example, but i can't figure out how to do moq with WPF and Postgres for testing upload file function.

** What i want to do is - using uploading function in WPF without touching db to do Moq.**
Right now, i stuck on upload function in WPF class which contain upload method that come up with connection to db.

Here is Some Source Code

```
public static async Task<IDeviceFileViewModel> WriteDeviceFilesAsync(IDeviceFileViewModel device)
    {            

        IDeviceFileViewModel deviceResult = device;

        //check file storage path
        var filestoragepath = FileSystemEngine.CheckFileSystemStoragePath(device);

        //delete log file
        //Trace.WriteLine(device.DeviceId);
        DeleteLog("Logs", device);

        foreach (var deviceFile in device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFiles)
        {

            //Start modified by Prin Sooksong 08/13/2017
            //check corrupted file
            MediaFile fileStats = new MediaFile(deviceFile);

            var deviceFileExt = Path.GetExtension(deviceFile);
            if (deviceFileExt.Equals(".WAV") || deviceFileExt.Equals(".wav"))
            {
                var audioStat = fileStats.Audio.FirstOrDefault();

                if (audioStat != null)
                {
                    device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile = new FileInfo(deviceFile);
                    var tuple = await Task.Run(() => WriteDeviceAudioFileAsync(device, filestoragepath));

                    deviceResult.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFileToCheckSums.Add(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
                }
                else
                {
                    //write log file
                    //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File"));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File");
                }
            }
            if (deviceFileExt.Equals(".MOV") || deviceFileExt.Equals(".mov") || deviceFileExt.Equals(".MP4") || deviceFileExt.Equals(".mp4"))
            {
                var videoStat = fileStats.Video.FirstOrDefault();

                if (videoStat != null)
                {

                    device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile = new FileInfo(deviceFile);
                    var tuple = await Task.Run(() => WriteDeviceVideoFileAsync(device, filestoragepath));

                    deviceResult.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFileToCheckSums.Add(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
                }
                else
                {
                    //write log file
                    //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File"));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File");
                }
            }
            if (deviceFileExt.Equals(".JPG") || deviceFileExt.Equals(".jpg"))
            {
                var pictureStat = fileStats.Image.FirstOrDefault();

                if (pictureStat != null)
                {
                    device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile = new FileInfo(deviceFile);
                    var tuple = await Task.Run(() => WriteDevicePictureFileAsync(device, filestoragepath));

                    deviceResult.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFileToCheckSums.Add(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
                }
                else
                {

                    //write log file
                    //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File"));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! Corrupt File");
                }
            }
            //End modified by Prin Sooksong 08/13/2017



        }            

        deviceResult.DeviceActiveStatus = false;


        return deviceResult;
    }
```

Another Method that is tricked when WPF can identify file extension

```
 internal static async Task<Tuple<string, byte[]>> WriteDeviceAudioFileAsync(IDeviceFileViewModel device, string FileStoragePath)
    {
        var config = configurationManager.GetConfiguration<ExtractorConfiguration>();


        NpgsqlConnection.MapEnumGlobally<ActivityTypes.Action>();
        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=" + config.DatabaseSetting.Host + ";" +
                                                                  "Port=" + config.DatabaseSetting.Port + ";" +
                                                                  "Database=" + config.DatabaseSetting.Database + ";" +
                                                                  "User Id=" + config.DatabaseSetting.UserName + ";" +
                                                                  "Password=" + config.DatabaseSetting.Password + ";")
        )
        {

            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw e;
            }

            try
            {

                    //var fileOid = await WriteFileOid(connection, device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile);
                    //convert .wav to .mp3 file
                    Tuple<FileInfo, DirectoryInfo> transcoded = StreamEngine.TranscodeDeviceAudioFile(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile);
                    device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded = transcoded.Item1;
                    device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioTranscodedDirectory = transcoded.Item2;


                    //write raw file to ubuntu file system
                    var filestoreRaw = FileStoragePath + @"\" + device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name;
                    await WriteFile(device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile, FileStoragePath);                       

                    //var transcodedAudioFileOid = await WriteFileOid(connection, device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded);

                    //write mp3 file to ubuntu file system
                    var filestoreMp3 = FileStoragePath + @"\" + device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded.Name;
                    await WriteFileMP3(device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded, FileStoragePath);

                    var fileChecksum = SecurityEngine.WriteFileCheckSum(device,device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile);

                    MediaFile fileStats = new MediaFile(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.FullName);
                    //MediaFile fileStats = new MediaFile(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded.FullName);
                    var audioStat = fileStats.Audio.FirstOrDefault();

                    //var audioSize = audioStat.Size;
                    var audioSize = fileStats.General.Size;

                var durationTime = audioStat.Duration;
                    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationTime);
                    TimeSpan fileDuration = new TimeSpan(t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

                    var fileCreated = device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.CreationTime;
                    var fileChanged = device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.LastWriteTime;

                    if (fileCreated.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
                    {
                        fileCreated = fileCreated.ToUniversalTime();
                    }
                    else if (fileCreated.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                    {
                        fileCreated = fileCreated.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime();
                    }

                    if (fileChanged.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
                    {
                        fileChanged = fileChanged.ToUniversalTime();
                    }
                    else if (fileChanged.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                    {
                        fileChanged = fileChanged.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime();
                    }

                    //Trace.WriteLine(fileCreated.Kind);
                    //Trace.WriteLine(fileChanged.Kind);

                    //var fileMimeType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.FullName);
                    var fileMimeType = getFileMimeType(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.FullName.ToUpper());

                    Guid deviceUserUuid = Guid.Parse(device.DeviceUserUuId.ToString());
                    Guid deviceIDUuid = Guid.Parse(device.DeviceIdUuid.ToString());
                    Guid id = Guid.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(device.DeviceId);
                    var deviceId = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

                    Guid activityId = Guid.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    var fileTitle = getMediaTitle(device);

                    var metadatainfo = MetaDataEngine.getMetaDataInfo(device);


                //DoEvents();

                if (metadatainfo != null)
                {

                    var sqlInsertGrp = "INSERT INTO " +
                                                "audios (id, created, duration, device_id, user_id, modified, checksum, file_path, file_extension, file_size,prev_file_path,mime_type,title, classification, description) " +
                                                    " VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12::mime,@p13,@p14::classification,@p15);" +
                                       "INSERT INTO " +
                                                "activity (id, user_id, entity_id, user_ip, action, entity_type) " +
                                                    " VALUES (@a1, @a2, @a3, @a4, @a5, @a6);";

                    using (var sqlGrp = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlInsertGrp, connection))
                    {
                        //Audio part
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, id);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileCreated);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", NpgsqlDbType.Interval, fileDuration);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceIDUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceUserUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileChanged);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", NpgsqlDbType.Bytea, fileChecksum);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", NpgsqlDbType.Text, filestoreRaw);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", NpgsqlDbType.Text, "WAV");
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", NpgsqlDbType.Text, audioSize);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", NpgsqlDbType.Text, filestoreMp3);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", NpgsqlDbType.Text, fileMimeType);

                        //audio file meta data                            
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", NpgsqlDbType.Text, metadatainfo.Title);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", NpgsqlDbType.Text, metadatainfo.ClassificationData);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", NpgsqlDbType.Text, metadatainfo.Note);

                        //Activity part
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, activityId);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceUserUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, id);

                        //IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
                        //                                  .AddressList.(f => f.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

                        IPAddress ip = GetIP();

                        var ipStr = Utf16ToUtf8(ip.ToString());
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", NpgsqlDbType.Text, ipStr);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", NpgsqlDbType.Enum, ActivityTypes.Action.upload_audio);
                        //Start modified by Prin Sooksong 08/07/2017                    
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", NpgsqlDbType.Text, "audios");
                        //End modified by Prin Sooksong 08/07/2017

                        sqlGrp.Prepare();
                        await sqlGrp.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    var sqlInsertGrp = "INSERT INTO " +
                                                "audios (id, created, duration, device_id, user_id, modified, checksum, file_path, file_extension, file_size,prev_file_path,mime_type,title) " +
                                                    " VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12::mime,@p13);" +
                                       "INSERT INTO " +
                                                "activity (id, user_id, entity_id, user_ip, action, entity_type) " +
                                                    " VALUES (@a1, @a2, @a3, @a4, @a5, @a6);";

                    using (var sqlGrp = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlInsertGrp, connection))
                    {
                        //Audio part
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, id);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileCreated);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", NpgsqlDbType.Interval, fileDuration);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceIDUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceUserUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileChanged);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", NpgsqlDbType.Bytea, fileChecksum);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", NpgsqlDbType.Text, filestoreRaw);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", NpgsqlDbType.Text, "WAV");
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", NpgsqlDbType.Text, audioSize);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", NpgsqlDbType.Text, filestoreMp3);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", NpgsqlDbType.Text, fileMimeType);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", NpgsqlDbType.Text, fileTitle);


                        //Activity part
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, activityId);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, deviceUserUuid);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, id);

                        //IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
                        //                                  .AddressList.(f => f.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

                        IPAddress ip = GetIP();

                        var ipStr = Utf16ToUtf8(ip.ToString());
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", NpgsqlDbType.Text, ipStr);
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", NpgsqlDbType.Enum, ActivityTypes.Action.upload_audio);
                        //Start modified by Prin Sooksong 08/07/2017                    
                        sqlGrp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", NpgsqlDbType.Text, "audios");
                        //End modified by Prin Sooksong 08/07/2017

                        sqlGrp.Prepare();
                        await sqlGrp.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    }
                }

                //write file to ubuntu file system
                //var filestoreRaw = FileStoragePath + @"\" + device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name;
                //await WriteFile(device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile, FileStoragePath);
                //write file to ubuntu file system
                //var filestoreMp3 = FileStoragePath + @"\" + device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded.Name;
                //await WriteFile(device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceAudioFileTranscoded, FileStoragePath);

                //delete temp mp3 file
                await StreamEngine.DeleteMP3File(transcoded.Item1);

                    disconnected = false;
                //write log file
                //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tUploaded successfully"));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tUploaded successfully");

                    var tupleChecksum = new Tuple<string, byte[]>(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.FullName, fileChecksum);
                    return tupleChecksum;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("duplicate key value"))
                {
                    device.DuplicateFileErrorCount++;

                    disconnected = false;
                    //write log file
                    //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! File already exists"));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\tSkipped! File already exists");

                    //delete duplicate file on samba server
                    FileSystemEngine.DeleteFile(device, FileStoragePath);

                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                    //{
                    //    MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Duplicate file '" + device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "' found in camera '" + device.DeviceId + "'.\r\nClick OK to continue.", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    //}));
                }
                else
                {
                    device.UnknownErrorCount++;

                    disconnected = true;

                    //write log file
                    //var taskWriteLog = Task.Run(() => WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\t" + e.Message));
                    WriteLog("Logs", device, device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.Name + "\t" + e.Message);

                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                    //{
                    //    MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Error with camera '" + device.DeviceId + "'.\r\nDescription : " + e.Message + ".\r\nClick OK to continue.", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    //}));

                }

                var tupleChecksum = new Tuple<string, byte[]>(device.DeviceFileStatisticsModel.DeviceFile.FullName, new byte[] { });
                return tupleChecksum;
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to test UI and database with unit tests? 
1st thing - you have to test only application logic - and you have to "trust" external libs.
2nd thing - Data layer and user interface layer should be separated from each other - so they should not appear in one test
3rd thing - please use interface in parameters of your functions and wrap external things to make your code testable.

You can use fluent nhibernate for example for integration tests with DBs. For WPF - you don't need to use it - just test your view model.

Uploading functionality is also hard to test - because you need to load file somewhere (so IO, memory...), save it somewhere, and check if file is in correct place and check if content of the file is the same- it is too much for unit test, with or without UI and DB.

Which logic you want to test?

Comment: I try to extends class from WPF [which attached upload method with sql and all kinds of database connection] to do Moq.What i want to test is using upload function in WPF without touching database. So that i can focus on uploading file. I am new for Moq , if you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: More Information, My WPF class is restrict for accessibility. So it quite difficult for me to do Moq.

Comment: 1st thing - you try to do too much at once - please split functions :)
2nd : you have function WriteDeviceFilesAsync with parameter device - so please mock IDeviceFileViewModel and IDeviceFileViewModel and just check for example how many times one of function is called. Your current code is hard to test, because it hard to define how IDeviceFileViewModel must looks like for which IDeviceFileViewModel.

Comment: So I have to check about Does "Upload function" has been called successfully ?. Right ?. Because if i have to touch with File i have to care a lot of things such as codec , IO and so on.

Comment: It depends what you need to test. Normally unit tests tests:
1) if function returns correct output for current input
2) if function throws exception as expected
3) if function open connection/create file/... as expected (integration)
4) if function set correct fields/properties to correct values in current object
5) if function calls correct other functions (if call, how many times)
6) if function hit correct event
7) if edge cases works as expected
8)  ...

So you don't check everything - only you check if function works as expected. Only one function at once - not everything

Comment: Thank you for explaination . I will try to follow your example for unit test.

Comment: Can i ask 1 more question ?. Moq will not do the real execution Right ?. For example, i have real class/interface that including add 1 rows in database [Let's call AddDatabase] then i extends this class into FakeAddDatabase After that add into mock [ var mock = new Mock<FakeAddDatabase>(); 
 which return message the status] then  mock.Setup(x => x.InsertDatabase(ID)).Returns(status);

Comment: Of course, you can write in memory DB tests with moq and in this case nothing in your real DB will be saved. Check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/478504/Moq-Mock-Database